# How to refresh $state when user update the controller in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular UI Router and would like to reload the current state and refresh all data / re-run the controllers for the current state.

How can i reload the state with new data using `$state.reload()` and `$stateParams` ?

app.js

```
.state('app.editControl', {
            url: '/edit/control',
            params: { controlId: null,processId: null, from: null, controlInProcessKey:null, refresh:null},
            templateUrl: 'views/control/createNewControl.html',
            controller: 'CreateControlCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.updateCallBack = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $scope.statusInfo = '';
    }, 1000);
    if ($scope.editControlToRisk) {
        console.log('EDITCONTROL');
        if ($scope.controlDTO.controlInProcessDTO.processKey) {
            $state.go('app.alignCtrlToProcess', {
                controlId: $scope.controlDTO.controlKey,
                controlInProcessKey: $scope.controlDTO.controlInProcessDTO.controlInProcessKey,
                processId: $scope.controlDTO.controlInProcessDTO.processKey
            });
        } else {
            $state.go('app.home');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('EDIT');
        $state.go($state.current, {
            controlId: $stateParams.controlId
        }, {
            reload: true
        });
        $scope.selectedAlignProcesses = new Date().getTime();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
$state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {reload: true});// can check with inherit {reload: true, inherit: false}
```

and you should use `$scope.selectedAlignProcesses = new Date().getTime();` before `$state.go`

Comment: i edited my question and i added as per your answer for some reason its going to `app.home`  i see in console log printing '`EDIT'

Comment: that's means satisfied `if($scope.editControlToRisk)` condition and not satisfied `if ($scope.controlDTO.controlInProcessDTO.processKey)` condition so go to `app.home` state its not reload issue its your logical issue

Comment: then why its logging `EDIT` in console  that is part of else and reload

Comment: what is your current state?